# How to use self in lazy initialization in Swift

Tags: swift

Some websites recommend to initialize views using lazy initialization instead of using a storyboard.

It works when `self` is not used in lazy initialization.
But when `self` is used in it, a compile error occurs.

For example, in the following code, `label1` can be compiled successfully, but `label2` can't, because `self` is used in it.

How to use `self` in lazy initializations?

```
class A {
    private let label1: UILabel = {
        return UILabel()
    }()

    private let label2: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        self.addTextToLabel(view) // compile error !!!
        return view
    }()

    private func addTextToLabel(label: UILabel) {
        label.text = "test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is written under the misunderstanding that you are currently using lazy initialization. But you are not. Both `label1` and `label2` are not using lazy initialization. They are being initialized immediately when `A` is being initialized and this is the cause of the error since `self` isn't ready when these property initializers are called.

The solution is to actually make `label2` a lazy property.

```
private lazy var label2: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    self.addTextToLabel(label: view)
    return view
}()
```

But note that this `label2` initialization will not happen until the first time you actually try to access the `label2` property.

As per the docs:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.
>
> Lazy properties are useful when the initial value for a property is dependent on outside factors whose values are not known until after an instance’s initialization is complete.

Reference:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html